# Change comparator in prolog rbtree

Tags: prolog

I am using the swi-prolog rb_trees. The standard implementation uses "==" to compare values, I need to use "=@=", is there some way to do it?

If it is not possible I guess I would need to find some other representation for the clauses I store in the tree. The clauses have this format for example:

```
cl(daughter(X,Y), [female(X), parent(Y,X)])
```

I need the above clause to be equal to for example this clause:

```
cl(daughter(A,B), [female(A), parent(B,A)])
```

One function that gives the same output only for =@= clauses is portray_clause i guess. However it doesn't have an output argument, so I am not able to store the output of portray_clause into rb_tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use numbervars/3 on the clauses for storing them in the red-black tree and varnumbers/3 to get the original clause back? The predicate numbervars/3 will ground the clauses and maybe that will make the use of (==)/2 work for your case?

Comment: thanks numbervars did exactly what I needed :) I did not even need varnumbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to change the predicate used for comparisons.

The best solution is probably to use ground terms as keys, since then the difference between `==` and `=@=` disappears. (In fact, using ground terms is a good idea anyway, since you don't want a variable binding that occurs in between tree operations to invalidate the tree's order property.)

Comment: I don't think it's possible in my case, I am programming some ILP, and I need to keep the closed list of the clauses searched so far. I've solved it using list, but rb_tree would really speed things up

Comment: @HonzaBrabec: then you may need to devise some alternative representation of the clauses so that you can use the clauses as values in the tree, rather than keys. (Maybe just integers?)

Comment: I've thought about it but I would need some injective function, not just hash, and two =@= functions would have the same value... actually thats the second part of my original question :)

Comment: Actually the function portray_clause gives results I need but it doesn't have an output argument

Comment: @HonzaBrabec: can you maybe edit the question to elaborate a bit more? This is an interesting problem (one of the few advanced Prolog questions I've seen on this site), and I'd love to help, but I'm not sure I understand the details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: OK I've written a bit more.